# I find some problem during during the configuration of my development environment sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, nodejs

here is the command I executed:  yo @microsoft/sharepoint

At the end of the execution of this command I reach the expected result despite having encountered these errors or I wonder if these errors can really cause problems after ??
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run the **gulp serve** command, if your web part gets rendered, then no issues with this error. If it doesn't get rendered, try running the **npm install node-sass -g** command. 
Then subsequently keep follow the command in the screen for any errors, this is the beauty of the SPFx, the developer will be instructed in the screen what to do for the errors.

The error comes from node-sass module installation, so run the below command:

```
npm install node-sass -g
```

Actually, the above errors come from **node_models** where some of the files didn't get added properly.

One more workaround is, develop just hello world web part or download from the Github... then for any upcoming SPFx project just replace the **node_models** folder with the working one.

**Update**:

If the above command does not fix your issue - you can download the **node-sass.zip** file from this location:

https://github.com/Global-SharePoint/GetSharePointListItemsUsingSPFX/blob/master/node-sass.zip

Extract the zip file, you will get a folder **node-sass**

Then go to your project file path like below:

"Your Project Path"\node_modules

Example:

"C:\Temp\SPFx\ReadSPListItems\node_modules"

[image: node-sass folder path under the node_modules]

Rename the existing "**node-sass**" as **node-sass2** then copy the downloaded **node-sass** folder and paste here (or even you can replace the existing **node-sass** folder)

Then, finally, run the **gulp serve** command again to see whether the web part renders properly without any errors.

For sample SPFx web part tutorial you may refer to the below articles:

- [Create custom property in SharePoint Framework – SPFx web part
  pane](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/create-custom-property-in-sharepoint-framework-spfx-web-part-pane/)
- [Get list items from SharePoint using SPFx framework(No Javascript
  Framework)](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/get-list-items-from-sharepoint-using-spfx-frameworkno-javascript-framework/)